# Which is more appropriate, a reservation or an appointment at a beauty salon?

Tags: word-usage

Do you make a reservationt at a beauty salon? Or do you make an appointment at a beauty salon?

Comment: I don't know the answer to this question, but I do have a one-liner that should always be wheeled out when anyone asks you "Did you have a reservation?". There is only one correct reply to this: "Yes, I had many, but I've turned up anyway."

Answer (score 1):

Reservation is made for some place or facility while appointment is usually used for some person. In this case, appointment seems more appropriate as it depends on the availability of the hair dresser or the beautician at the salon.

Comment: Exactly. Appointments (http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/appointment) are made with people and reservations (http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/reservation) are for things.

Comment: Which one is more appropriate probably depends on whether you're just establishing a time you'll be there, or that you'll get a specific beautician.